# In React native moment return only current date always when parsing a timstamp?

Tags: react-native, momentjs

**Problem:**

In React Native when parsing a timestamp moment return only the current date every time. This is my code.

```
let newDate = moment(selectedDate).format('DD MMMM YYYY')
```

When I pass these timestamp these only returns current date. 1606806931991, 1612336531991. I tried a lot to find out a solution for this. But I was unable to do so. Can someone help me to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: What does `selectedDate` look like when you pass it in?

Answer (score 0):

Please use once the following snippet. I guess this helps you

```
const selectedDate = 1606806931991;
const newDate = moment(selectedDate).format("DD MMMM YYYY");
console.log("New Date",newDate)
```